# A summation of the multiplication of reflected Mobius functions and their behavior for different values of $k$

Tags: summation, graphing-functions, visualization, mobius-function

$$ \Psi_k(N)=\sum_{n=1}^{N} \mu(n)\mu(k-n)$$

where $\mu(n)$ is the Mobius function.

This function is interesting to me because for the case of $k=N$ it has the symmetric property of being odd with respect to the midpoint of the interval, at $N/2$.

I tried to plot the function for multiple values of $k$ on the same plot but could not figure out how to do this on wolfram alpha.

I'm trying to see if by plotting many of these functions I can see a pattern emerge. Maybe the set of functions stay within some region on average.

I'd like the answers to include a plot of the function for $k=1,2,...,N$ all on the same plot to see how different they are.

Why does a little change in $k$ create such a big change in the overall behavior of the function?

Thanks.

Comment: What you said about the midpoint doesn't make sense. They are the coefficients of $f(x)^2$ where $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu(n) e^{-nx}$ is the inverse Mellin transform of $\frac{\Gamma(s)}{\zeta(s)}$, if all the zeta zeros are simple then $$f(x) = \sum_\rho \frac{\Gamma(\rho)}{\zeta'(\rho)} x^\rho +\sum_{k=0}^\infty (a_k+b_k \ln x) x^k$$ where $(a_k+b_k \ln x )x^k= Res(\frac{\Gamma(s) }{\zeta(s)}x^{-s},s=-k)$. The growth of the coefficients of $f(x)^2$ depends on the RH.

Comment: Calculate your sum for a suite of small values of $k$ and $N$, and then look up the resulting sequence at the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, oeis.org

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Trying it now @GerryMyerson

Comment: It's not on the Encyclopedia

Comment: https://oeis.org/A068341